# No stack trace for the message "Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite ..."

Tags: json, r, shiny

> Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future
>   version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named
>   vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want
>   JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON.

So I'm having this message when running a Shiny App, however not as an error or warning, the App is still running well. And it's not telling me where the error is.

I tried `options(warn = 2)` but nothing changed.

EDIT:

This code I made up might not make any sense, but I'm not allow to provide the source code. Fortunately/Unfortunately, the issue is still there.

```
library(shiny)

foo = function(data){
  plt1 = ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = as.factor(am)), data = data) + 
    geom_boxplot() + ggtitle('Boxplot:')

  mx = quantile(data$mpg,.999,na.rm = TRUE)
  plt2 = ggplot(data, aes(x=mpg, colour=as.factor(am))) + 
    geom_density(size=0.5)+  xlim(0,mx) + ggtitle('Density plot')

  list(data, plt1, plt2)
}

ui = fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("tbl"),
  plotOutput("plt1"),
  plotOutput("plt2")
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  o <- reactive({
    foo(mtcars)
  })

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    o()[[1]]
  })

  output$plt1 <- renderPlot({
    o()[[2]]
  })

  output$plt2 <- renderPlot({
    o()[[3]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Code might actually help here as we can only take your word for it. You might be directly or indirectly (via a wrapper function) calling `asJSON()` function showing warning.

Comment: @Parfait Sorry for the late reply. Please see my edit in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of debug the issue by running `debug(jsonlite:::warn_keep_vec_names)`.  It will break when the function giving that warning is called, and you can see what functions are active. When it stops in the browser, run `where` to see the active stack.  In RStudio, you can also see the stack trace in the Traceback pane:  you may want to enable `Show Internals`.